# Input field cursor not visible in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In HTML, I'm wrapping an input field inside a div and the cursor is not visible in that input field. This problem is visible only in Firefox and fine in all other major browsers.

I have attached a screenshot and also a JSFiddle link along with this post.
Please help me solve this problem.

[JSFiddle Link](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/2597)

Thanks in advance.